# Is there a better (closer to home row on keyboard) shortcut for the home directory in bash than tilde?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, directory

I don't like reaching for the tilde `~` key so often when I'm specifying file and program paths relative to the user home directory on the command line. Does anyone have any tips for cutting the number of keystrokes down?

Comment: reduce the number of keystrokes down from one?

Comment: @glenn: actually, there are two keyboard strokes required: Shift + \`

Comment: Plus pressing SHIFT is harder to do with the tilde key, esp one-handed.

Comment: unless you've one finger on a hand or an awful keyboard (like no Shift button on the left side), Shift + ~ is not uneasy with one hand.

Comment: I guess it's easier if I move my left hand to the left and use my thumb on the shift key. How do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot eliminate `~` completely, but at least there are some workarounds available.

These workarounds may not always be usable, but for other cases, it can be really helpful:

- Before doing the command, change your directory using `cd` (without arguments). This changes your working directory to `~`.
- If you frequently need to change the working directory to a folder within your home folder, use the `CDPATH` variable in bash. Run the next command to minimize `cd ~/folder` to `cd folder`, but still allow to change to a directory `folder` in the current directory if exist.

  ```
  CDPATH=.:~
  ```

  To make this change persistent, add the line to `~/.bashrc`. As its name may suggest, it only works for the `cd` command in bash.
- Use the `$HOME` variable if you really want to avoid `~`, in case the key would give you an electrical shock for example. This is especially useful in cases where tilde-expansion would not occur, between quotes for example (`"~"`)
- Create a function for a command. If you frequently need to copy files to a directory in your home directory as in `cp file ~/archive`, you can run the next code to create a function:

  ```
  cph(){ cp "$1" "$HOME/$2";}
  ```

  and use it as:

  ```
  cph file archive
  ```

  Note that you cannot pass arguments or multiple files to this function, that needs additional tweaking. As with the `CDPATH` hack, you can put it in your `~/.bashrc` file to make it persistent.